# Removing Docker on windows 10 with script file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have tried a lot of steps to remove docker desktop on my machine. It prompts a lot of errors during uninstallation. Performed the script file as well. But it still in the app list.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the installer package is not found to uninstall. Download Docker desktop installer and run it and then uninstall may work.

Comment: Is there any file at the specified location? It looks like an attempt has been made to remove docker but not through the normal procedure, instead deleted the files directly.

Comment: I deleted the files directly. Now I can't reinstall again :( Is there any possible solution to uninstall it properly?

Comment: First end all docker process through task manager

then do this

How to uninstall Docker Machine under Windows 10
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161471/how-to-uninstall-docker-machine-under-windows-10